# How to schedule a task on a given interval of time in a thread in java without using Timer or another thread?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I want to run a command on every 3 seconds in android. I have an application in android which is using a thread. Now in that thread i need to invoke a method but every 3 seconds. i.e when the thread starts
1
2
3 runCommand()
4
5
6 runCommand() and so on

I dont want to use any other thread or runnable nor I want to use Timer for that. What I can use is SystemClock.utilsmillis or System.nanoTime() and a couple of variables, something like that. Kindly help

Thanks

FAS

Comment: Why do you have those odd requirements? Why not use a thread or timer?

Answer (score 0):

Android has the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) mechanism, which is similar to a Timer, but it does not have its own thread, and gets called from the main event loop instead.

But if you use that, do not place code in there that will take a lot of time (or block), as that would hang the whole app.

(Actually, it sounds like you already have another thread for your, you could create a [Looper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) for it, and run the Handler off that one so as to not block the main thread).